# Hapi HTTP Server Error | NodeJS | UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: PerfHooks.performance.eventLoopUtilization is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpserver, hapi

I'm learning backend development using NodeJS with **Hapi** framework, and I got an error after starting the node with `npm run start`.

`server.js`

```js
const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
const init = async() => {
    const server = Hapi.server({
        port: 5000,
        host: 'localhost',
    });
    await server.start();
    console.log(`Server berjalan pada ${server.info.uri}`);
}
init();
```

`package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "hapi-web-server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@hapi/hapi": "^21.0.0"
    }
}
```

Running `npm run start` on PowerShell:

```
> hapi-web-server@1.0.0 start E:\DOCUMENT\Dicoding\hapi-web-server
> node server.js
(node:19696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: PerfHooks.performance.eventLoopUtilization is not a function
    at new Heavy (E:\DOCUMENT\Dicoding\hapi-web-server\node_modules\@hapi\heavy\lib\index.js:42:60)
    at new module.exports.internals.Core (E:\DOCUMENT\Dicoding\hapi-web-server\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\core.js:122:22)
    at Object.module.exports (E:\DOCUMENT\Dicoding\hapi-web-server\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\server.js:22:18)
    at init (E:\DOCUMENT\Dicoding\hapi-web-server\server.js:4:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\DOCUMENT\Dicoding\hapi-web-server\server.js:13:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:19696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19696) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I expect the output should be:

```
Server berjalan pada http://localhost:5000’
```

And when I enter `curl -X GET http://localhost:5000`, it should give this output:

```
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}
```

Comment: What version of node are you using? `performance.eventLoopUtilization` was introduced in node versions v14.10.0 and v12.19.0 respectively. So if you for instance are using node 14.7 or 12.16, that function won't exist yet.  And @hapi before version 21 didn't use this particular function, so downgrading resolves that probelm

Comment: My node version is `v14.8.0`. Will the problem fixed if I update my node to the latest version? @derpirscher

Comment: Yes, any node version >= 14.10 will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem could be solved with installing Hapi version `@hapi/hapi@^20.1.0`.

But that doesn't explain why the above code causes an error on Hapi version `@hapi/hapi@^21.0.0` (latest version / default from `npm install @hapi/hapi`)

## Edit

Explanation from [derpirscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776927/derpirscher):

> `performance.eventLoopUtilization` was introduced in node versions v14.10.0 and v12.19.0 respectively. So if you for instance are using node 14.7 or 12.16, that function won't exist yet. And @hapi before version 21 didn't use this particular function, so downgrading resolves that problem

My node version is `v14.8.0`
That's what causing the problem.

After knowing the problem, I tried installing `@hapi/hapi` and `nvm` to latest version and the problem solved.

I also learned that it's easier to maintain node version with **[NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)**.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create initial route

```js
const init = async () => {
    const server = Hapi.server({
        port: 3000,
        host: 'localhost'
    });

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: function (request, h) {
    
            return 'Hello World!';
        }
    });

    await server.start();
    console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};
```

Comment: I've tried the code, but it still gives me same error message. `TypeError: PerfHooks.performance.eventLoopUtilization is not a function` from `init();`